# MassTransit Server Side Encryption on Amazon AWS for SQS queues

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, masstransit

Is it possible to activate Server-side encryption (SSE) on Amazon SQS via MassTransit ? Can I set the Default Visiblity Timeout in SQS from MT ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to specify the attributes on the receive endpoint for both of these settings:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("my-queue", e =>
{
    e.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.VisibilityTimeout, "60");
    e.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.KmsMasterKeyId, "arn of key");
});
```