# Masstransit SQS SEE-SQS

Tags: .net, amazon-sqs, masstransit

How do I configure SQS to use SQS-owned encryption keys via Masstransit programmatically?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-sqs-sse-queue.html

The answer to this question ([MassTransit Server Side Encryption on Amazon AWS for SQS queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866228/masstransit-server-side-encryption-on-amazon-aws-for-sqs-queues)) suggest to use QueueAttributes, however I believe that's for SEE-KMS setup, and I can't find an attribute for SEE-SQS.

Comment: Looking at the latest code, SqsManagedSseEnabled attribute has been added to AWS SDK in Nov 2021, MT hasn't been updated to use the latest SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below doc it will resolve you issue

```
aws sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/account_no/Queuename --attributes SqsManagedSseEnabled=true
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/set-queue-attributes.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've just edited the question to clearly state that this needs to be done via Masstransit.